# How do I make a method work for any enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following code, where ApplicationType is an enum.  I have the same repeated code (everything except the parameter types) on many other enums.  Whats the best way to consolidate this code?

```
 private static string GetSelected(ApplicationType type_, ApplicationType checkedType_)
    {
        if (type_ == checkedType_)
        {
            return " selected ";
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Updated my answer to not be horribly, horribly, wrong.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Shooting from the hip, something along the lines of...</s>

```
private static string GetSelected<T>(T type_, T checkedType_) where T : System.Enum{
  //As before
}
```

Apparently that's illegal.

To simply cut down on repetition, you could just replace T with Enum thusly,

```
private static String GetSelected(Enum type_, Enum checkedType_){
  if(type_.CompareTo(_checkedType) == 0) return "selected";

  return "";
}
```

Though this doesn't get you much in the way of type safety, as two different enumeration types could be passed in.

You could instead fail at runtime:

```
private static String GetSelected(Enum type_, Enum checkedType_){
   if(type_.GetType() != checkedType.GetType()) throw new Exception();
   //As above
}
```

To get some compile time safety you could use a generic constraint, though since you can't using the Enum class you won't be able to restrict everything:

```
private static String GetSelected<T>(T type_, T checkedType_) where T : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible{
  if(!(first is Enum)) throw new Exception();
  //As above
}
```

The above will make sure you only pass Enums of the same type (you'll get a type inference error if you pass in two different Enums) but will compile when non-Enum's that meet the constraints on T are passed.

There doesn't seem to be a great solution to this problem out there, unfortunately.

Comment: *Constraint cannot be special class 'System.Enum'*

Comment: You would need to use the keyword "struct" because an enum won't work. You can do further type checking at runtime to ensure that it is infact an enum.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to do this through a generic constraint at compile time because an `enum` is really an `int`. You'll need to restrict the values at runtime.

Comment: A C# enum is *usually* an `int`, actually.

Comment: Whups, the latest project I've been working on maps enums to a byte in the database - confused. I'll update the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For equality on an emum? Simply:

```
public static string GetSelected<T>(T x, T y) {
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x,y) ? " selected " : "";
}
```

You *could* add `where T : struct` to the top line, but there isn't a *need* to do that.

For a full example including demo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        ApplicationType value = ApplicationType.B;
        Console.WriteLine("A: " + GetSelected(value, ApplicationType.A));
        Console.WriteLine("B: " + GetSelected(value, ApplicationType.B));
        Console.WriteLine("C: " + GetSelected(value, ApplicationType.C));
    }
    private static string GetSelected<T>(T x, T y) {
        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y) ? " selected " : "";
    }
    enum ApplicationType { A, B, C }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this appropriate for your needs?

```
private static string GetSelected<T>(T type_, T checkedType_)
    where T: struct
{
    if(type_.Equals(checkedType_))
        return " selected ";
    return "";
}
```